# I have a memory leak in this objective-c method, can anyone tell me where?

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory, memory-management, exc-bad-access

I'm receiving an exc_bad_access somewhere in the code below. I don't understand where it is if anyone could shine any light on it? It's a method that takes in an NSMutableArray of dictionaries and sorts them by one of the elements in the dictionary. The memory leak is almost certainly in the bit with the block but I think i'm missing something fundamental in finding it...

```
-(NSMutableArray*)sortBicyclesByDistanceToDevice:(NSMutableArray*)inputArray{

    NSArray *arrayToHoldSorted = [[[NSArray alloc] init];

    arrayToHoldSorted = [inputArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(id a, id b){

        NSNumber *first = [[a objectForKey:kDistanceFromDevice] objectForKey:kValue];
        NSNumber *second = [[b objectForKey:kDistanceFromDevice] objectForKey:kValue];
        return [first compare:second];}];


    NSMutableArray *retVal = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    retVal = [arrayToHoldSorted mutableCopy];

    [arrayToHoldSorted release];

    return [retVal autorelease];
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You allocate arrayToHoldSorted (1) - which you never use as you then get an NSArray back from sortedArrayUsingComparator(2). And then you release it afterwards(3) when you don't own it. You do the same trick for retVal, allocating a NSMutableArray - then overwriting your reference to it by getting a new NSMutableArray from [arrayToHoldSorted mutableCopy];

```
NSArray *arrayToHoldSorted = [[NSArray alloc] init]; .. // 1

arrayToHoldSorted = [inputArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(id a, id b) ..... // 2

[arrayToHoldSorted release]; // 3
```

Just assign the return NSArray from sortedArrayUsingComparator to a reference...

```
NSArray* arrayToHoldSorted = [inputArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(id a, id b) .....
```

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you assign `retVal` to an `NSMutableArray` through then reassign immediately after. The original alloced `NSMutableArray` will leak. That is:

```
NSMutableArray *retVal = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
retVal = [arrayToHoldSorted mutableCopy];
```

Should be:

```
NSMutableArray *retVal = [arrayToHoldSorted mutableCopy];
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace:

```
NSMutableArray *retVal = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
retVal = [arrayToHoldSorted mutableCopy];
```

With:

```
NSMutableArray *retVal = [arrayToHoldSorted mutableCopy];
```

You are leaking the first value of retVal.

Answer (score 2):

There's more than one in there!

This line:

```
NSArray *arrayToHoldSorted = [[[NSArray alloc] init];
```

Is a memory leak since you immediately reassign the pointer. It should be removed. Just declare your array on the next line:

```
NSArray* arrayToHoldSorted = [inputArray sortedArrayUsingComparator...
```

This method returns an autoreleased object, so you don't need to release it later on.

A similar pattern with the mutable array. You alloc/init, then overwrite with a new object, giving another leak. Again, remove the alloc/init line and just declare in the next line. mutableCopy gives you an implicitly retained object, so you do need to autorelease it.

You seem to be under the impression that alloc/init is needed every time you declare an object variable. This is not the case.

Comment: I was under that impression actually. I think my mem management needs work

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that in this line:

return [retVal autorelease];

you release something that you have not retained. Also in this line:

NSArray *arrayToHoldSorted = [[[NSArray alloc] init];

you have an extra [, which does not help. But most importantly, you can use the static analyzer in XCode to diagnose this sort of bug, rather than pestering the good folk on StackOverflow.

Comment: I'd never heard of the static analyser, i'll have a look, thanks

Comment: When you press Command-B to build your project - try instead Shift-Command-B to Analyze. It's also available off the Product Menu and even from the Run button if long click it. The analyser is your friend. I try to force myself to analyse every 4th or 5th build to keep my [sucky] memory management skills in order

Comment: It is definitely worth keeps ones code free of analyzer "bugs", even if it means rewriting a section of code where the analyzer just does not get it. Do as Damo suggests. Do not do what I did. I left it to the end of a very large project, and it took me ages to clean everything up. Definitely worth it though.